# Is this mod_rewrite rule correct?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Are these url rewrite rules and conditions correct?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Basically, URL needs to be rewritten from non-www to www.

Thanks

Comment: Isn’t it working or why are you asking?

Comment: just asking, the one up there isn't working at all :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use a more generic rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But this rule does the same.